# Create contact record from registration form in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, saas, erp, odoo-9

Using Odoo 9 SA, I've added custom fields to my crm.lead model and added those fields to a registration form. I'd like to have that custom lead information carry over to the contact record that is created in res.partner when the lead is qualified.

My question is how can I go about doing that? I don't know where the action is that would copy the fields from crm.lead to res.partner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add these fields to res.partner model and it will store it (related fields would be best choise I think)

Comment: Awesome.. thanks for that! That makes complete sense.